# Change copy text to WebSearch text using SelectableText in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change the option "copy" to "WebSearch" by using SelectableText Widget and when user click on WebSearch then selected text search to web

```
SelectableText.rich(
TextSpan(
text: model.messageBody!=null?message:'',
 // default text style
  ),
```

toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(),
)

Comment: Please post more of your code.

Comment: I only have this code.